# Vue form submit and asynchronous javascript function is not working properly

Tags: javascript, vue.js, asynchronous, async-await

I'm doing an asynchronous function after i submit a form in Vue.js and i want to do console.log() data from the inputs of the form but when i send the data to the function which returns a promise i get empty. This is happening since I have another function which should delete the fields of user input, this method should be executed after the above mentioned function is completed. I tried through console.log() to see the ranking of how the functions are executed and the ranking seems to be fine. When I remove the second function I accept the data in the first method very well.

**State:**

```
 data() {
    return {
      contactData: {
        displayName: "",
        email: "",
      },
```

Method when i submit the form:

```
 methods: {
    async handleSubmit(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      await createContactMessages(this.contactData);
      this.clearFields();
```

**createContactMessages** function:

```
    export const createContactMessages = (contactData) => {
        let resolvedFlag = true;
        return new Promise((resolve ,reject)=>{
          setTimeout(()=>{
            if(resolvedFlag){
              console.log('createContact called')
              console.log(contactData); // Returns displayName: "" and email: "". 
              resolve("Resolved");
            }else{
              reject("Rejected")
            }     
          }, 1000);
        });
}
```

**clearFields** function in Vue:

```
clearFields() {
      console.log("clearFields Called");
      this.contactData.displayName = "";
      this.contactData.email = "";
      console.log("clearFields Finished");
}
```

**Callstack:**

```
console.log('createContact called')
console.log("clearFields Called");
console.log("clearFields Finished");
```

If i remove clearFields(); data returns well, i can not understand why?

Comment: Can you show your input code?

Comment: @edisonthk - 
`<form class="contact-form" @submit="handleSubmit">
<FormInput
  name="displayName"
  type="text"
  :handleChange="handleChange"
  :value="contactData.displayName"
  label="Your Name"
></FormInput>` - handleChange is a function that gives an effect to the input. Inside FormInput i have an <input /> that takes name, type, label, and value from props. :/

Comment: As you are using vue.js, why don't you try v-model instead of handleChange `<input v-model="contactData.displayName" placeholder="edit me">`

Comment: Because i want to make this component reusable. I have tested it in other parts and it works well.

Comment: I have tried your code and it works, I think there is problem in your FormInput
https://codepen.io/edisonthk/pen/JjEBwBp?editors=1111

Comment: you should use the v-model but I think the problem is handleChange function, show your handleChange function.

Comment: @edisonthk - The input form component works well, but today when I did `console.log (contactData.displayName)` the data appeared !!!! While when I do `console.log (contactData)` all values are `""` I forgot to try this way. But why aren't they showing up when i'm doing `console.log(contactData)` ? I can't understand. @AhmadKZX - i think handleChange is fine but here it is.

`handleChange(event) {
      const { value, name } = event.target;
      if (name == "displayName") {
        this.contactData.displayName = value;
      }`

Comment: @sycamore55  good to hear that. Well, console.log problem is not related to this thread, you should start another thread if you are interesting. Have a nice day